# Unexpected $end in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following error message about my functions.php file in Wordpress. Even after deleting the functions.php file, I'm still getting the same error!

Does anyone have any ideas what I can try to resolve this?

http://paintedonwater.com/wp

Edit:

The functions.php file code is pasted below. Note that I have REMOVED this file but I am still getting the same error.

```
    <?php

// add 'Music' post type

add_action( 'init', 'create_music_post_type' );
function create_music_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'music',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Music' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Music Release' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Release' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5, 
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'music'), 
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        )
    );
}


// add 'Press' post type

add_action( 'init', 'create_press_post_type' );
function create_press_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'press',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Press' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Press Feature' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Press' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5, 
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'press'), 
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        )
    );
}


// add 'Blog' post type

add_action( 'init', 'create_blog_post_type' );
function create_blog_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'blog',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Blog' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Blog Post' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Blog' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 4, 
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog'), 
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        )
    );
}

//Remove all Twenty Eleven Sidebars

add_action( 'after_setup_theme','remove_twentyeleven_all_widgets', 100 );
function remove_twentyeleven_all_widgets() {

remove_filter( 'widgets_init', 'twentyeleven_widgets_init' );
}


//Add Twitter widget area

function twitter_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Twitter',
        'id' => 'twitter',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twitter_widgets_init' );

//Add Album widget area

function album_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'New Album',
        'id' => 'new_album',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'album_widgets_init' );


//Add thumbnail sizes

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post','page' ) );
add_image_size('album-artwork', 166, 166, true);
add_image_size('gallerix-thumbnail', 175, 114, true);

//Add custom footer message

    function remove_footer_admin () {
    echo 'Fueled by love, music and <a href="http://www.wordpress.org" target="_blank">WordPress</a> | Designed by <a href="http://www.electrickiwi.co.uk" target="_blank">Electric Kiwi</a>';
    }

    add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'remove_footer_admin'); 

?>
```

**UPDATE: All seems to be working now. I had to remove the functions.php file via the File Manager as somehow the FTP doesn't seem to be working correctly. After uploading via that, all seems to be ok. Thanks for everyone's answers.**

Comment: Usually means you're missing a closing `}` or have an extra `}`

Comment: Even after adding the closing } I was still getting the problem. How can I still be getting this error even now that the functions.php file has been removed via FTP?

Comment: You're missing a closing } or have an extra }.You need to post wp-content/themes/powtheme/functions.php  content to resolve this.

Comment: @devo I've posted the content above. But my main issue is that even after removing the file, I still get the same error?

Comment: Now I can't see any errors here http://paintedonwater.com/wp/

Comment: Yes, I went into the File Manager to remove the functions.php file and it then finally removed it (it wouldn't remove via FTP somehow). But now that I've reuploaded the functions.php file, none of my custom functions are working. I think perhaps there is a delay on the server or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

- Add a closing PHP tag `(?>)` at the end of your file
- Reupload your file to the server. Sometimes I get the same error as
  you and it does the trick. This could be caused by a ftp error.
- And also check `}`

at the end .

Comment: @Vibs_cool I've reuploaded but still the same error even after adding the missing }

Answer (score 1):

Check there whether there are spaces at the end of the file or you can paste your code here, your link cannot give any idea as to what exactly is wrong with your code.

Comment: @NDM I've posted the code above. The thing that is confusing me is that even after removing the file, I'm still getting the exact same error... I've now reuploaded it after adding the missing } but still getting the error message.

Comment: FYI, this is not my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the file via the File Manager and reuploading (after adding the missing } from one of the functions) has resolved the issue. FTP was not working which was making me think that the file had been removed/overwritten successfully when in fact it was not!